# Grammar checker for Linux?

Tags: linux, spellcheck

Is there something for Linux that comes near to the MS Word grammar checker?

Wish list:

- Emacs support
- Ignores Latex markup

Comment: Do you mean "grammer" or "syntex"? ;-)

Comment: Should it detect wrong grammar or are you looking for a spell checker (="Rechtschreibung" vs. "Grammatik")

Comment: A grammar checker is not about orthography, it's about the proper use of the subjunctive and dangling participles and so on.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Ispell](http://kb.iu.edu/data/abap.html), a **spell-checking** program available for many Unix implementations. For shell prompt usage, enter:

```
ispell filename
```

Here is a description [how to use it in Emacs](http://kb.iu.edu/data/abap.html).

For **grammar** checks, you could use [diction](http://kb.iu.edu/data/actd.html):

```
diction mytextfile | more
```

It finds wordy or badly written sentences.

Comment: Tried using `diction` myself, but the results were disappointing. I gave it a short run of text (an abstract for a proposal), and the three things it complained about were:
1. Use of the word "phase".
2. Use of the word "dependable".
3. Use of the word "system".
As this was for a Phase II effort dealing with systems of systems (and our company name is Dependable Computing), needless to say this was less than helpful. Maybe this is not representative.
Still, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try [GNU Aspell](http://aspell.net/) ?

> GNU Aspell is a Free and Open Source spell checker designed to eventually replace Ispell. It can either be used as a library or as an independent spell checker. Its main feature is that it does a superior job of suggesting possible replacements for a misspelled word than just about any other spell checker out there for the English language. Unlike Ispell, Aspell can also easily check documents in UTF-8 without having to use a special dictionary. Aspell will also do its best to respect the current locale setting.